# NPM how do you install another dependency from a subdirectory of another Git repository?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, yarnpkg

In package.json using npm, how do you install another dependency from a subdirectory of another Git repository?

For example, I have tried:

npm install
my package.json ....

```
  "dependencies": {
    "some-package": "git+https://github.com/myTeam/myrepo.git#develop/folder-with-a-package-json",
    "lodash": "4.17.14"
  },
```

- The remote dependency has valid package.json in the sub directory
  folder-with-a-package-json.
- The remote repo is public.

Error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: git checkout develop/folder-with-a-package-json
npm ERR! error: pathspec 'develop/folder-with-a-package-json' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Comment: This is not possible. See the discussion on npm's GitHub issues: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974

Comment: Oh no. Any alternative solutions?